# How to filter a model based on the latest instance in relation to that model, in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

To simplify I have two models, `Product` and `ProductStatus`. To record the history of the product status, they are tied with one-to-many relationship with `Product` being the parent.

Now the question is: **How do I query the `Product` model based on the latest status of the `ProductStatus` tied to it?**

Let's say I want to query a Product that has a status of "Approved", then the rough idea will probably be something like:

```
// The status model has a field called status
Product::whereHas("statuses", fn($q) => $q->whereLatest("status", "Approved"))
```

Note: I need this code in builder instance because I'm assuming I'm going to query a lot of data.

How can I do this?

Comment: you need to first define a "latest" relation, than you can query if that relation has status "Approved"

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to create a property on the `Product` model for the current status and create a model observer to monitor changes in this property and create a `ProductStatus` when necessary. Since you will query a lot of data this will be way more efficient and faster.

Answer (score 0):

**Create scope inside the Product Model**

```
public function scopeStatus(Builder $query, $status)
{
    return $query->relation()->where('status', $status)->latest();
}
```

**Use:**

```
Product::status('Approved')->get();
```